# building nested resources for a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, associations, nested-forms, nested-resources

I have a class User which has sub classes IndividualUser and BusinessUser (through STI). IndividualUser and BusinessUser have a many-to-many association and are linked through a join table called Employees.

Also, a User can have an Account.

I'm trying to set up a nested form, and am struggling to create the required objects.

My models:

```
class User
   has_one :account
end

class IndividualUser < User
    has_many :business_users, :through => :employees
    has_many :employees
end

class BusinessUser < User
    has_many :individual_users, :through => :employees
    has_many :employees
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :business_user
    belongs_to :individual_user
end

class Account  
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Now, in my controller, I am able to create a new account for an individual user:

```
# GET /individual_users/new
def new   
    @individual_user = IndividualUser.new
    @individual_user.build_account
end
```

This works fine.

However, when I try to create a business_user, then individual_users, and then an account for each individual_user:

```
# GET /business_users/new
def new         
    @business_user = BusinessUser.new

    @business_user.employees.build()
    @business_user.employees.each do |employee|
        @individual_user = employee.build_individual_user
        @individual_user.build_account
    end
end
```

I get the following error:

```
undefined method `build_account' for nil:NilClass
```

It appears as though @individual_user is not being created.

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. Any ideas?

What's really strange, is that if I instead move the code to the view, it appears to work. i.e. in my view:

```
<% @business_user.employees.each do |employee| %>
    <% employee.individual_user.build_scoot_account %>
    <% employee.individual_user.scoot_account.id = 2 %>
    <%= employee.individual_user.scoot_account.id %>
<% end %>
```

This displays "2".

Comment: what happens if you try  @individual_user.account_build,  though maybe take a look at nested_form as really helps with model associations

Comment: doesn't work unfortunately. i get an undefined method error.